# xilinx jtag cable

Tags: schematics, jtag

could anyone please explain to me what are the CTRL and PROG pins in [this](http://www.xilinx.com/itp/3_1i/data/common/jtg/dppb/appb.htm) schematic good for? with CTRL i know what does it do but i don't much get the purpose, so far i would say it's there just to make the schematic look nice..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CTRL pin enables the DIN, TMS_IN and CLK signals so that they "reach" TDI, TMS and CCLK on the JTAG and FPGA headers.

The PROG pin is similar, it will pull down the line that goes to TDO and D/P.

I'm not exactly sure why it is wired as it is, but I'm sure that they're not just there to make the schematics look nice. I couldn't find any links that referenced the link you gave so I can't find any more information on the exact device you're looking at.

Comment: OK but what would be the point in sending 1 to CTRL? it would disable the signal of those 3 other pins right? TDO is actualy supposed to be output pin, it is true though whenever i set PROG to 1 the DONE pin gives 1 and vice versa..

Comment: I would guess it is used when the JTAG header is not used. If the CTRL line is enabled the DB25 connector will drive the signals to the FPGA. If it is not, the JTAG header will drive the signals.

Comment: oh.. I thought it's just the other way around, I'll try it out. thank you

Comment: That's what I think at least, but it's kinda hard to be entirely sure without looking at a bigger picture.

Comment: It would also be nice if you could accept my answer if you're satisfied with it.